# How to set high I/O priority permanently in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, performance

After I upgraded from Windows 10 Home to Pro one of the process which usually consumes high CPU usage keeps getting its performance limited, resulted in very poor outcome from that process. I tried to set the CPU priority but the performance only improved temporarily, specifically when switching from one priority to another regardless of lower or higher prioritization. I then changed the I/O priority through Task Manager which helped improved the performance temporarily, it cannot be set permanently using task Manager as there is no option to do so, in 1-2 minutes Windows will low this I/O priority down again. Is there any way to set the I/O priority to Normal or High permanently?

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party tools you can use like " Process Hacker ", "Prio" as mentioned in the previous answer.
On another hand,
If you don't want to use a third-party tool then you have to create a shortcut to that program with a command-line argument

```
"cmd /c Start “” /High “C:\Users\User\Desktop\Program.exe”
```

[Program Shortcut Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVx8K.png)